# I want to create a drop down using Javascript for my web page in django

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates, dom-events

Basing on the data type of the column selected on first drop down the columns of the second dropdown should be displaying the value in the below Javascript dictionary,
note: here `{{col.1}}` give the details of SQL column data type like varchar, int

Below in my html code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Modal Header</h4>
                <!--                      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 
                Header</h4>-->
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>This is a small modal.</p>
                <p>
                    <select id="columnname" name="columnname" class="form-control"
                            onchange="changecat(this.data-val);">
                        <!-- onchange="populatefilter()"-->
                        {% for col in column_names_nd_Data_type_tupl %}
                        <option data-val="{{col.1}}" value=" {{col.1}}"> {{col.0}},{{col.1}}
                        </option>

                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <br>
                <hr>
                </select>
                <select name="datatype" id="datatype">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                </select>

                <hr>

                <select id="datatype" name="datatype" class="form-control">


                    <option value="<"> less than</option>
                    <option value=">"> Greater than</option>
                    <option value="="> equal to</option>


                </select>


                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mealsByCategory = {
    bigint: ["<", ">", "=<", ">="],
    varchar: ["contains", "exact", ],
    datetime: ["options", "<", ]
}

    function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("datatype").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (categoryId in mealsByCategory[value]) {
                console.log("value",+value)
                catOptions += "<option>" + mealsByCategory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("datatype").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    }
</script>
```

How to display the SQL filter operation based on data type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django Javascript dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763701/django-javascript-dropdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*it worked changed the method to getAttribute*

```
function changecat(value) {
    if (value.length == 0) document.getAttribute("data-val").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
    else {
        var catOptions = "";
        for (categoryId in mealsByCategory[value]) {
            console.log("value",+value)
            catOptions += "<option>" + mealsByCategory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("datatype").innerHTML = catOptions;
    }
}
```